# How to read a value returned by a function in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have written a shell script to pass array as an argument to a function and select one element of that array and return it back to caller. The script works fine unless I assign the return of my function call to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

operations=(Sleep Eat Play Study)
services=(Cook Clean Draw)

readOption(){
  _arr=("$@")
  #echo "${_arr[@]}"
  #echo "Value of #1 is $@"

  MAX_TRIES="5";
  COUNT="0";

  while [[ -z "$opt" && "$COUNT" -lt "$MAX_TRIES" ]]
  do
    if [ "$COUNT" != "0" ]
    then
       echo "WARN: Retries left [$((MAX_TRIES-COUNT))]. Choose the correct option."
    fi

    for i in "${!_arr[@]}";
    do
      echo $((i+1)). "${_arr[$i]}"
    done
    read -rp "Choose an option>" index;
    COUNT="$((COUNT+1))"
    opt="${_arr[$((index-1))]}"
  done
  
  if [ "$COUNT" -eq "$MAX_TRIES" ]
  then
    echo "ERROR: Exceeded maximum number of retries: $MAX_TRIES";
    echo "Exiting......";
    exit 1;
  fi
  value="${opt,,}"   # Lower casing the chosen option
  unset opt
  echo "${value}"
}

opr=$( readOption "${operations[@]}" )  # It works fine if I remove the assignment
svc=$( readOption "${services[@]}" )    # It works fine if I remove the assignment

echo "Operation is: $opr"
echo "Service is: $svc"
```

What is wrong with the assignments that script doesn't work as expected? Thanks

### Updated-1:

Expected Output:

I want to display all array elements.
Allow the user to choose one option from array.
Return the option chosen in function to a variable in main script.

### Update-2:

Updated the scripts as suggested in accepted answer.

Comment: I do not understand. `doesn't work as expected?` - but what is expected? How do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 3):

`$(...)` grabs stdout of what is inside. So:

```
readOption() {
    read -p "This is printed on stdout!" ...
    echo "this is also printed on stdout"
    echo "${value}"      # and this is too!
}
opt=$(readOption)  # takes **ALL** stdout messages and assigns them to opt
```

I believe for you current approach would be best to fix all quoting mistakes and check your script with http://shellcheck.net and pass the variable name by name and use namereference, to mimic `read`:

```
readOption() {
    local opt value _arr COUNT MAX_TRIES  # do not pollute global space
    declare -n _readoption_var=$1 # namereference - use unique name to avoid nameclashes
    shift
    _arr=("$@") # properly quote varibale expansions
    ... etc. etc. your code ...
    _readoption_var="$value"
}
readOption opr "${operations[@]}"
```

Alternatively you could handpick messages and write the output to console separately from writing to stdout:

```
readOption() {
    read -p "Print to console" var >&3 
    echo "print this to console too" >&3
    echo "$value" # but print this to stdout
} 

exec 3>&1 # duplicate/"clone" stdout on 3rd file descirptor
opt=$(readOption)  # stdout will go to opt
                   # but fd3 will go to terminal
# or:
opt=$(readOption) 3>&1
```

Comment: Could you please help me understand the purpose of 3>&1?

Comment: To duplicate stdout on 3rd file descriptor. Because stdout inside `$(...)` is redirect to be grabbed and assigned to `opt`.

Comment: If 3 has some meaning associated to it? or I can use 4,5,6 or any number?

Comment: you can use any free number, even `exec {var}>&1` and then use `$var`. Just the messages have to be redirected to that file descriptor connected to scripts stdout.